# Need help with HttpWebRequest on a Compact Framework Project

Tags: c#, windows, windows-mobile, compact-framework, httpwebrequest

not so long ago I´ve created a small iphone app for my Daily use. Now I want to port this app to a Windows Mobile Device while using C# and the Compact Framework. But I really have no clue how to use the HttpWebRequest and the msdn doesn´t help me either. I think I have a lag of understanding on how Web Requests work in general.

In the iPhone app I have the following lines code:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://xxx:xxx@api.test.net/RPC2"]];
[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[theRequest addValue:@"text/xml" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
[theRequest setCachePolicy:NSURLCacheStorageNotAllowed];
[theRequest setTimeoutInterval:5.0];
NSString* pStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><methodCall><methodName>xxx.SessionInitiate</methodName><params><param><value><struct><member><name>LocalUri</name><value><string></string></value></member><member><name>RemoteUri</name><value><string>xxxx</string></value></member><member><name>TOS</name><value><string>text</string></value></member><member><name>Content</name><value><string>%@</string></value></member><member><name>Schedule</name><value><string></string></value></member></struct></value></param></params></methodCall>", number.text, TextView.text];
NSData* pBody = [pStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[theRequest setHTTPBody:pBody];
NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
```

The Webservice has no wsdl so I have to use the HttpWebRquest Object in .Net CF.
What I didn´t get is, where to put the Body (the long XML) in my Request?

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(@"https://xxx:xxx@api.xxx.net/RPC2");
req.Method = @"POST";
req.ContentType = @"test/xml";
req.Timeout = 5;
```

I started this way, is the first line it´s own HttpWebRequest and for the XML Body I have to create anotherone?! How do I use it correctly, how do I send it? Sorry if this might be normaly totaly easy but I really don´t get it. I´ve searched the web, 2 Books and the msdn but in every tutorial is only a Webrequest with an URL but without a body.

Thank you

twickl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write the POST data to the [request stream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d4cek6cc.aspx).

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(@"https://username:password@api.sipgate.net/RPC2");
req.Method = "POST";
req.ContentType = "test/xml";
req.Timeout = 5;
using (Stream stream = req.GetRequestStream())
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
{
    writer.Write("PUT THE XML HERE");
}

using (StreamReader reader = req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
{
    string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the request stream using

```
Stream requestStream = req.GetRequestStream();
```

Then write your xml data to the stream, taking care to encode your text.

Don't forget to close the stream to ensure that all of your data is sent.

```
requestStream.Close();
```

Comment: If the stream is in a using, it should get flushed and closed at the end of it.

Answer (score 0):

BEWARE, if there's no data to write to the stream, the `ContentLength` would be 0 but oddly you STILL need to `Dispose()` the RequestStream even if you don't write anything to it!!!

```
req.ContentLength = 0;
req.GetRequestStream().Dispose();
```

This problem only happens in Compact Framework.

I want my 8 hours back, and my hair too...